# dotnet core runtime Odroid c2

Tags: 16.04, dotnet, arm64

Did anyone try to install dotnet sdk or runtime on Odroid c2 ubuntu 16.04.
According [official microsoft guide](https://www.microsoft.com/net/learn/get-started/linux/ubuntu16-04) this is possible, but installation failed:

---

```
...
odroid@odroid64:$ sudo apt-get update
odroid@odroid64:$ sudo apt-get install dotnet-sdk-2.1.101
```

output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree 
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package dotnet-sdk-2.1.101
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'dotnet-sdk-2.1.101'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'dotnet-sdk-2.1.101'
```

maybe it's because of the  odroid arm64 architecture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found fresh issue about this problem:
https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/17044

There is no dotnet core for arm64 yet.